# Алгоритм поиска похожих материалов

Tags: php

Хочу на сайте в конце каждой статьи сделать колонку "похожие материалы". Искал в Я и G, но толку 0. Может быть, кто-нибудь поделится своими наработками или подскажет, где искать что-то подобное?

Comment: На движке "вордпресс" есть плагин на твою тему, посмотри исходник, возможно появятся идеи.

Comment: related post yet вроде называется :)
тяжело такие исходники понимаются :(

Comment: Заводишь метки, похожие материалы отдаешь по меткам, легко и просто и не нужно программирование искуственного интеллекта =)

Comment: я думал наж этим вариантом: суть выдачи похожих постов в увелечении переходов по сайту и времени проведенном на сайте, но проблема в том, что стьям одной сути, можно дать разные метки + по схожим меткам могут выводиться статьи разной тематики.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется [Латентно-семантический анализ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7)

Comment: спасибо, изучаю

Answer (score 1):

http://bionicspirit.com/blog/2012/01/16/cosine-similarity-euclidean-distance.html

Можете посмотреть лекции по анализу данных.

- http://compscicenter.ru/program/lecture/4952
- http://compscicenter.ru/program/lecture/4953